# How to generate a unique row ID to uniquely identify cart item in shopping cart using PHP?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, shopping-cart

I am developing an ecommerce website that contains a cart that is managed using sessions. User selects some products and upon selection whole product information is added to session as array. Now when user updates items in the cart e.g changes quantity how do I identify which product was selected by the user to be changed? I am developing the application using Codeigniter PHP framework? Codeigniter does have cart library that has this functionality that generates unique row ID for each selection the user makes. But I have come too far in my own custom cart development and don't want to revert back to use CI cart. 
Any ideas how do I generate unique row ID for each array that is pushed to session array when user puts items into cart?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the uniqid function from PHP, http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php This gives you a unique id. Or serialize the array you want to identify to an id, but this means that the unique id will change when the user changes his selection.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate unique ids by concatinating the user information or if you want numeric id then you can use the random string generator function as:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 5) {
    $characters = '0123456789';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString; }
```

you can change the length of string and also the valid characters.